# Omitting special characters from the string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to implement some type of pixel for analytic and it requires passing a session Id in the url string. My sessionID contains special characters. It looks something like this **BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309**
I need to remove the (-!) characters from this string, how do I achieve this using jquery? I need to make sure jquery remove those characters before it render otherwise it will not report a visit to analytic.

Guys thanks your help but maybe I need to explain bit further, my pixel code look some what like this "

img src="https://sometime.com/png?org_id=k8vif92&session_
id=T6PtTyRSqhGPYBhp84frwth67n6fL7wcLBFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-130901808!1319637471144&m=2&m=2" alt="">

Before this pixel fire off, I need to replace the character in the sessionId string to remove !- and keep in mind session id will change every time there is a new session. I need a code that is generic so it works no matter what session id is, it needs to delete special characters from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.replace`:

```
var token = "BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309";
token.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, "");
```

this will remove any character that's not a letter or number. More concisely:

```
token.replace(/\W/g, "");
```

(this won't replace underscores)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but keep in mind that session id characters will not be same everytime it runs, depend on session it will change. I only need to remove the special character no matter what session id other letters are

Comment: Yes, that was just example code. But the regular expression will work for an session id

Comment: Instead of replacing the explicit characters as others has suggested, he creates a set of all the characters you do want, and takes then inverse of that set...therefore, it replaces all the characters yo do not want...it will work for all strings

Answer (score 1):

Black-listing `!` and `-` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6pda/)):

```
var url = "BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309";
document.write(url.replace(/[!\-]/g,""));
```

White-listing alpha-numeric ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPkwN/)):

```
var url = "BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309";
document.write(url.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig,""));
```

Comment: As an aside, the `-` need not be escaped when it's the last character in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309".replace("!-","");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/eYCjX/

Comment: This may be too specialized...it only will replace the first occurring match...and it must be in that order...the other regex solutions would be better

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to know whether dashes/bangs or other non-numerics could be legal in the string. Based on the information provided this is a very straight-forward way of removing the two characters mentioned.

If there is a desire to remove all non-numerics or all instances of "!" or "-", yes there could be better solutions.

Comment: Just trying to help @mblase75. If the OP mentioned wanting to remove all variants of those two characters I'd have approached it differently.

Comment: @mblase75: I must say I like nheinrish's approach. 1) It's straight and to the point; 2) people are too quick to conclude regex (esp. given the brevity and vagueness of the original question); 3) It's a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: I do want all the special characters omitted, This solution works but it only eliminate the first instance of (!-) and leave the last ! in the string.

Comment: If you want to omit all instances of both ! and - you can use: str.replace(/[!-]/g,""). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/zQ5Ya/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need jquery for this. You can use javascript regex. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3dUT/)

```
var code = "BFhGlzT6FBkDr2Zndp0!-1309";

code = code.replace(/[!-]/g,"");

alert(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a regular expression character set that contains all the allowed characters. For example, yours might look like `/[a-zA-Z0-9]/`. Now invert it with the *complementary character set* `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` and remove all those characters with the `String.replace` method.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
```